# Describe the corresponding quotient space (the set and its open subsets).

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}$ (with the standard topology) be given the equivalence relation where $x \sim y$ if $\lfloor x \rfloor = \lfloor y \rfloor$ (here $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the greatest integer smaller than x). Describe the corresponding quotient space (the set and its open subsets).

Any hint/solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Consider the map $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb Z:x\mapsto\lfloor x\rfloor$. What subsets $A$ of $\Bbb Z$ have the property that $f^{-1}[A]$ is open in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Aren't all subsets A of $\mathbb{Z}$ open in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @KangHoonYou: Yes, but that isn’t the question. What subsets $A$ of $\Bbb A$ have $f^{-1}[A]$ open in $\Bbb R$? To get started, see if you can work out what $f^{-1}[\{1\}]$ is.

Comment: Isn't $f^{-1}[\{1\}]=(1,2)$?

Comment: @KangHoonYou: Almost: $f(1)=1$ also, so it’s $[1,2)$. In general $f^{-1}[\{n\}]=[n,n+1)$. What unions of intervals of that kind are open? HINT: Apart from the empty union, they are all unions of infinitely many of these intervals.

Comment: How about the union: $(n-1,n] \cup [n, n+1)$? This is open!

Comment: @KangHoonYou: But it isn’t $f^{-1}[A]$ for any $A\subseteq\Bbb Z$. The closest is $A=\{n-1,n\}$, but its inverse under $f$ is $[n-1,n+1)$, not $(n-1,n+1)$.

Comment: Interesting. How about if you let the subset of $A=\{n-2,n+1\}$? Wouldn't this work?

Comment: @KangHoonYou: Then $f^{-1}[A]=[n-2,n-1)\cup[n+1,n+2)$, which again is not open.

Comment: So is there no subset A of $\mathbb{Z}$ that have the property that $f^{-1}[A]$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @KangHoonYou: There are infinitely many that have that property. Suppose that $0\in A$; then $[0,1)$ is going to be part of $f^{-1}[A]$. In order to make $f^{-1}[A]$ open, you’re going to have to make sure that $f^{-1}[A]$ contains an interval on the left side of $0$, and the only way to do that is to have $-1\in A$, so that $[-1,0)$ is part of $f^{-1}[A]$. Now $f^{-1}[A]$ contains $[-1,1)$, and we have the same problem with that endpoint $-1$. Okay: stick $-2$ into $A$, so that $[-2,-1)\subseteq f^{-1}[A]$; now $f^{-1}[A]$ contains $[-2,1)$. ...

Comment: ... Can you figure out what else to add to $A$ to make $f^{-1}[A]$ open without expanding it to the right as well as to the left?

Comment: What happens if you make $A={\n-1,n,n+1\}$?

Comment: @KangHoonYou: You get $[n-1,n+2)$, which doesn’t help. As long as $A$ has a smallest element, $f^{-1}[A]$ is going to have a left endpoint and won’t be open.

Comment: @KangHoonYou: What does that even mean? How do you subtract $1$ from the set $\{n-1,n\}$?

Comment: Essentially, I'm trying to find a way to define A such that A does not have a least element.

Comment: How about if you define $A=\{ -\infty, n\} $? Would that work? Since then, you would not have a least element.

Comment: @KangHoonYou: Wrong notation, but I think that you have the right idea. You want $A=(-\infty,n]=\{k\in\Bbb Z:k\le n\}$, right? Yes, that works: $f^{-1}[A]=(-\infty,n+0)$, which is open in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thank you so much Brian! You really are a great advisor!

Comment: @KangHoonYou: You're welcome, and thank *you*!